# Reloading page while an Ajax request in progress gives empty response and status as zero

Tags: ajax

Browser is Firefox 3.0.10. I am requesting a page using Ajax. The response is in progress may be in readyState less than 4. In the meantime I am trying to reload the page. The request ends, giving an empty response.

I used alert to find what string has been given as response text. I assume that by this time the ready state 4 is reached. Why it is an empty string?

When I alert the xmlhttpobject.status it displayed 0.

When I alert the xmlhttpobject.statusText an exception occurs, stating "NOT AVAILABLE".

When I read in the document http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/33024/0/page/2 it said for 3 and 4 `status` and `statusText` are available, but when I tested only status is available, but not satausText.

Here is sample code.

Consider that I have requested a page and my callback function is as follows

```
function cb(rt)
{
   if(rt.readyState==4)
   {
      alert(rt.status);
      alert(rt.statusText); // which throws an exception
   }
}
```

and my server side script is as follows

```
sleep(30);
//flushing little drop down code
```

Besides these I noticed the following.

Assume again I am requesting the above script using Ajax.
Now there will be an idle time of 30 seconds.
Before that 30 seconds I press refresh.
I got xmlhttpobject.status as, 0 but still the browser did not reload the page until that 30 seconds. Why?

When I refresh a page before an Ajax request is complete, the status value is set to zero and the ready state is set to 4, but the page still waits for the response from the server to end.

What is happening?

THE REASON FOR ME TO FACE SOME THING LIKE THIS IS AS FOLLOWS.

Whenever I do an Ajax request, if the process succeeded like inserting some thing or deleting something I popup a div stating that updated successfully, and I will reload the page. But if there is any error then I do not reload the page, instead I just alert that unable to process this request.

If the user reloads the page before any of these requests is complete, I get an empty response which in my calculation is there is a server error. So I was debugging the Ajax response to filter out that the connection has been interrupted because the user had pressed reload. So this time I don't want to display "unable to process this request" when the user reloads the page before the request has been complete.

Oh... a long story. IT IS A LONG DESCRIPTION SO THAT I CAN MAKE EXPERTS UNDERSTAND MY DOUBT.

So what I want form the above.

Any type of answer would clear my mind. Or I would like to say all type of answers.

EDIT: 19 dec.
If I don't not get any correct answer then I will delete this question and will rewrite with examples. Else I will accept after experimenting.

**I will create a demo program, and I will post the link here so that I can make you understand of what I am facing. Today is 29.dec.2010.**

Comment: What browser are you experiencing this with?

Comment: my first line... firefox 3.0.10

Comment: Try lowering the sleep time to 10 seconds Maybe the request timesout in 30

Comment: A basic question to you, Why u should want to reload the page?? Ajax is only meant for adding contents and checking status without reloading pages and if u r going to reload the page just post things and reload the page with fresh elements itself.. I think u r wrong in choosing both ajax and reloading the page..

Comment: +1 good explanation of a difficult situation

Comment: @kvijayhari. In a page i am displaying products which is fetched from another site by using ajax. so a request is started using ajax which will request my php script which in turn will fetch info from an external site then the response is flushed to the browser as json. the callback function displays 4 to 5 products with images. this displaying of products is set to run in certain intervals. user will want to navigate to another page at that time if there is a pending response then the page is not navigating. for more description please read my article again.

Comment: i will create a demo program and i will post the link here so that i can make you understand of what i am facing. today is 29.dec.2010.

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with browser version.

The moment the browser detects a change in page (eg a reload) it aborts all [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) calls. Every browser does that. And it's the decent thing to do.

My question would be: why are you reloading the page when/while an ajax request is working?

My solution would be: keep track of all ajax requests and abort them 'manually' (yes, you can do that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#abort() when you leave the page (`onunload` or `onbeforeunload`).

Answer (score 1):

You are using a pretty old version of Firefox there. 3.0.10 came out a year and a half ago. Lots has changed since then. There are some old Mozilla and Firefox bugs regarding this. They're closed and it looks like they were closed when Firefox 3 was in beta, but you never know, there may have been a regression. This is one possibility: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=511383

So, this is what I think is happening. I suspect that hitting reload causes any open http request to be aborted. Historically, Firefox hasn't handled abort too well - I think they intend for the readyState to be 0, but it cycles through 4 on the way there.

I recommend that you (and your users) upgrade your Firefox if possible. If that isn't possible, you'll have to work around this somehow. Testing for status == 0 and preventing your alert from firing would be a place to start. You could also set a flag in the onBeforeUnload event of window.

Comment: IE the same. No difference between FF and IE ragarding this. Today since the internet connection was slow in my office i cannot do cross site scripting using ajax and php and i couldn't reload page because of the pending request... so i had to close and open the browser. anyway today i am going check with other browsers. besides i have used ajax in all  my projects. getting a response is not a problem i had already done with your suggestion but the page dosent navigate untill the complete response is returned.

Comment: Its not entirely surprising that you get the same behavior form IE. Firefox does model some behavior off of IE, I recall reading that this is how IE handles is in one of the FF bug posts. Anyhow, it seems that I don't completely understand the question. I guess I'll wait for the 19th...

Comment: i will create a demo program and i will post the link here so that i can make you understand of what i am facing. today is 29.dec.2010.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it turned out to be the issue with PHP session.
If the session is open, all other requests from the same session must wait.

To fix this you make sure you do not start the new session in your server-side scripts.

This might be a problem if you are using some framework and it starts the session automatically. In that case simply add this line at the beginning of all your long polling server-side scripts:

```
session_write_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same issue, and let me share with you what I have done to make it working. 
I have given the parameter `global:false` while framing ajax request. So, even if we navigate to any other page, with the ajax request on the fly, it will launch the page as desired.

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same problem (in Chrome), and to me it seems like when I hit refresh in the middle of an xhr request the browser treats it as an error. So if we have specified an error block in our `$.ajax` call, the browser pops this as an error.

As a workaround I specified only a success block and the error disappeared. It looks like this is a scenario which should be handled by the browser itself.

Comment: Nice, but this could do as a comment instead of an answer