# Ajax Request in Progress suddenly started returning status = 0

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a web project in PHP and it accesses a Java Project that uses the Restlet Framework. The web project is running on Apache and I am testing it using localhost. The Restlet Framework also uses localhost as the domain, but the url is slightly different: localhost:8888/

This is the Javascript that, using Ajax, makes a call to one of the Java classes (CollectionPublic) using the URL above.

```
var url = "<?php echo $config['restServer_url'] ?>collectionPublic";

var params= "pageList="+facebookPages+"&time="+time;

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("POST", url,true);
client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

client.onreadystatechange = function () {

  if (client.readyState != 4) return;
  if (client.status != 200 && client.status != 304) {

       alert("error "+client.status);

 } else {
       alert("success");            

 }

 callback(client);
}

if (client.readyState == 4) return;
client.send(params);
```

I have tested and the call is being made correctly, using the URL localhost:8888/collectionPublic, and it is reaching the CollectionPublic class (the class is working fine).

The PROBLEM is: When this call is made, the CollectionPublic class takes a long time to complete its task, and the user should be able to access other pages (on the same server) or reload the page. However, when either of these things happen, the alert("error "+client.status) pops up and the value of client.status is 0. The call is then aborted, but the CollectionPublic's task continue normally, and when it finishes, nothing happens in the web page (before, the alert("success") was being fired).

I spent hours trying to figure out what was causing the error, since this was working last week. Most of the posts I found said that it could be a Cross-Origin Resource problem, since localhost and localhost:8888 are not considered as the same domain. To see if that was really the problem, I started Chrome using the --disable-web-security argument (and it was really disabled) but the issue was still there. 
The weirdest thing is that it has worked before, and I changed absolutely NOTHING in the code.

I have seen this post [Reloading page while an Ajax request in progress gives empty response and status as zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202060/reloading-page-while-an-ajax-request-in-progress-gives-empty-response-and-status) and it seems quite similar to what I am facing.

Hopefully, I have made myself clear, but if you have any doubts regarding this issue, just ask.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that the ajax request itself is quite right. `if (client.readyState != 4) return;` will always be true aside from when its actually 4. This may be better:

```
client.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(client.readyState < 4) {  
        //not complete yet
        return;  
    }  

    if(client.status != 200 && client.status != 304) {  
        //an error
        alert("error "+client.status);
        return;  
    } 

    if(client.readyState === 4) {  
        //complete
        callback(client);  
    }
}
```

As for the problem whereby the ajax call is aborted: This is correct behaviour. All XHR calls will be aborted by the browser as soon the page is reloaded or unloaded. Perhaps this was somehow not the case when viewing pages locally. I would not allow the user to navigate away (or reload) whilst the ajax in progress. As a work-around, your class could set a session variable that is read by your page.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I changed from client.readyState != 4, to client.readyState < 4, but this didn't interfere on my issue. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: But on this case, I think it is reasonable for the user to be able to navigate away or reload, since the task run by the Java class takes a while to be completed. I have seen in many forums that all XHR calls will be aborted when the page is reloaded, but the case is that it was working before! It might be something to do with what is said on this: http://ajaxian.com/archives/xmlhttprequest-and-status-code-0 but I still wasn't able to find if there was one tiny detail that was changed from the version that was working.

Comment: I have been testing my code a lot since yesterday and I found out that not only the client.status is 0, but the readyState is 4, as if it was complete (but it isn't). One basic doubt: Why does the READY STATE is even triggered by refreshing the page? I thought it was only triggered by a response from the server, which is clearly not the case. Can anyone clarify that for me?

Comment: A readyState of 4 but status of 0 suggests a cross domain policy issue to me.

Comment: At first when I started digging into the problem, the cross domain policy issue really seemed to be what was going on. But what makes me think this isn't the answer is that this code has worked before and I tried starting Chrome using the --disable-web-security argument and the problem was still there.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that the class being called by the request (localhost:8888/collectionPublic) has this line:      responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");

Comment: Is it possible that it has something to do with the browser itself? Because I am pretty sure it was working last week, but as now it isn't, maybe it is due to an update on something. Although I tested on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

Comment: I'm at a loss. Maybe your localhost:8888 is not returning the correct headers but I still suspect a cross domain issue. Google '[localhost ajax](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=localhost+ajax)' - there are others experiencing similar issues.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Moob. I have tried googling a million of things related to this issue, but no luck so far :( The cross domain issue is highly suspicious indeed, although the argument --disable-web-security when starting Chrome would have "solved" the problem, and it hasn't.