# ASP MVC, jQuery issue returning error on ajax post when user hits enter key whilst textbox has focus

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

First off. I am using ASP MVC 4, C# and Jquery 1.9.1.

I have a very unusual error where an ajax post is returning on its error handler when no error is present.

Basically I have written a search box and hooked this into returning a partial view for the search results when no errors with the model are found. Alternatively if errors are found the page will be redirected to the initial action method. CUrrently the only model error I trap is whether or not they have entered anything in the search box. However I perform a check in jQuery so this kind of makes it a moot point.

All of this is triggered by either pressing the enter key, or by clicking the search button with the mouse.

These events will both call the same jQuery function. Here is the jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#search-button').on('click', function () {
    runSearch();
});

$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        runSearch();
    }
});

/* Set loading dialog */
function disableScreen() {
    $('#dialog').attr('title', 'Please wait...').attr('id', 'dialog').html('<p>Loading... Please wait.</p>').dialog({
        open: function () { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        show: 'fade',
        modal: true
    });
}

/* Remove loading dialog */
function enableScreen() {
    $('.ui-dialog:has(#' + $('#dialog').attr('id') + ')').empty().remove();
    $('#dialog').html('');
}

function runSearch() {
    var searchTxt = $('#SearchString').val();
    var searchbox = $('#search-text');
    var parent = $('#search-results');

    /* Start search if search text is greater than 0 characters */
    if (searchTxt.length > 0) {
        disableScreen();

        $.post('/Search/OrderSearch', { 'searchString': searchTxt }, function (data) {
            parent.html(data);
            searchbox.val(searchTxt);
            $(window).scrollTop('0');
        }).success(function () {
            enableScreen();
        }).error(function () {
            alert('Error');
            enableScreen();
        });
    } else {
        alert('Please enter a search string');
    }
}
});
```

Now this all works perfectly fine if you:

1. Enter a name to search in the text box, click out of the box and press the enter key
2. Enter a name to search in the text box, click the search button with the mouse

This falls over if you:

1. Enter a name to search in the text box and then press the enter key (without exiting the text box)

The controller does not return an error, it returns the partial in every instance. However when the error is triggered, the entire page is rendered as the partial, not the targeted parent object.

To me this is very bizarre behaviour. Firstly why does jQuery think there is an error since the controller does not pass one back and secondly why does jQuery re-render the entire page as the partial data returned when it has a target to render too?

EDIT:

This is the response returned an all cases (even when it mucks up)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2013 12:30:40 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 777
Connection: Close

<table id="search-table" class="results-table">
<tr>
    <th>Order No</th>
    <th>Budget</th>
    <th>Client No</th>
    <th>Client Name</th>
    <th>Post Code</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
</tr>
        <tr data-id="11767" class="clickable">
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                2014/15
            </td>
            <td>
                MC0000
            </td>        
            <td>
                My Company Ltd
            </td>
            <td>
                123 456
            </td>
            <td>
                31/10/2013
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: jQuery will trigger an error if the server send back a empty response  declared as json Content-Type. Did you check the actual response is not empty ? http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-ajax-returning-a-json-result-of-an-empty-string

Comment: Hi Zzir, as mentioned the response returned is always the partial view the controller never returns an empty result but somehow the error handler is triggered in jQuery if you do not click out of the text box when hitting enter.

Comment: So you say that with a 200/OK response to the POST you go into the .error() ? Could you give us the response content in such a case ?

Comment: Hello Zzir response added to question above.

Comment: no </table> markup at the end ? Though I am not sure if this could trigger an error

Comment: Ah no that's just stack missing it off the end. Edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press enter in an input box, usually, the form is submitted.

This appears to be what is happening, when the user presses enter in the textbox, the form submits via a http post, and the response is rendered as a new page.

Try something like the following javascript to the page to prevent the form submission.

```
$('#SearchString').parent('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Kami, this appears to be the problem. I have added a line similar to yours in my jQuery and this has now cured the problem. Still very strange that the jQuery function fires and returns on its error handler but I can live with that!

Comment: Isn't it because you set callback on keypress, that is caught before the event goes up to the form element ? If you use keyup instead of keypress you'll probably never go into your code, since the form will submit and reload the page at keypress upward propagation.

Comment: Could it be that the AJAX POST that you still perform is interrupted by the reload : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202060/reloading-page-while-an-ajax-request-in-progress-gives-empty-response-and-status but then you should get an empty reponse to your AJAX call...